# Разбить строку на подстроки по количеству символов

Tags: регулярные-выражения, строки, подстрока

Есть длинная строка

```
abcdef ... xyz
```

Эту строку нужно разбить на подстроки по n символов
Как это сделать с помощью регулярного выражения? Подстроки должны разделяться переносом строки

Comment: Regexp в данном случае не нужен, это явный перебор.

Comment: Решение зависит от конкретных требований. Если нужно избежать деления слов на части, корректная работа с эмотиконами, ответ вовсе не очевиден.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Замените 5 на ваше n.

```js
var input = 'qwertyuiopasdfghjklg';
var result = input.replace(/.{1,5}/g, '$&\n');
console.log(result);
```

Произодится глобальная замена групп по пять символов на эти же самые символы + перенос строки. В самой последней группе может быть меньшее количество символов, поэтому чтобы вставить перенос и в конец, определена нижняя граница для квантификатора.